# Building Apps with Kivy

Tags: python, mobile, kivy

I am working on a plan for a mobile app which is in the very early stages of development. Background: The mobile app will be available on Apple and Android. It will allow the user to log in and see which local taxi companies will arrive the quickest, payment will be made through the app, a map will show the drivers location, in a nutshell.

Now the tech part, i am currently studying Python, still consider myself a junior. Could anyone advise if Kivy with Python would be able to handle these kind of functionalities that the app will need?

Further more could anyone shine some light on what kind of back end technology and functionalities I will need to incorporate also.

I have never created a Mobile app before so any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can technically achieve this with Kivy, but you'd be touching lots of features that are not well supported with existing helper modules - that includes payment processing, map display, to some extent login functionality (although this doesn't need anything special, it just adds to the pile).

If you aren't very experienced, I think you'll probably find it easier to use a more widely used framework with more examples.

Comment: More widely used frameworks’ referring to swift and kotlin?